# Azure via Python API - Set Storage Account Property - Allow blob public access To Disabled

Tags: python, azure

I'm trying to use python 3 in order to set property in Azure : Allow Blob public access
I didn't find any information on the net on how to implement this via python,
I did find solution via Powershell: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/blobs/anonymous-read-access-configure?tabs=powershell

looking for solution for python3...

[image]

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Allow Blob public access` feature is newly added in the latest python sdk [azure-mgmt-storage 16.0.0](https://pypi.org/project/azure-mgmt-storage/).

When using this feature, you need to add this line in your code:

```
from azure.mgmt.storage.v2019_06_01.models import StorageAccountUpdateParameters
```

Here is an example, it can work at my side:

```
from azure.identity import ClientSecretCredential
from azure.mgmt.storage import StorageManagementClient
from azure.mgmt.storage.v2019_06_01.models import StorageAccountUpdateParameters

subscription_id = "xxxxxxxx"    

creds = ClientSecretCredential(
    tenant_id="xxxxxxxx",
    client_id="xxxxxxxx",
    client_secret="xxxxxxx"
)

resource_group_name="xxxxx"
storage_account_name="xxxx"

storage_client = StorageManagementClient(creds, subscription_id)

#set the allow_blob_public_access settings here
p1 = StorageAccountUpdateParameters(allow_blob_public_access=False)

#then use update method to update this feature
storage_client.storage_accounts.update(resource_group_name, storage_account_name, p1)
```

Answer (score 0):

I haven't tried this myself, but looking at the [Python Storage Management SDK](https://pypi.org/project/azure-mgmt-storage/) and the REST API this should be possible.

Look [here](https://github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-python/blob/master/sdk/storage/azure-mgmt-storage/tests/test_cli_mgmt_storage.py#L144) for an example on how to create a new storage account using the Python SDK. As you can see, the request body seems to be pretty much exactly what gets passed on to the [underlying REST API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/storagerp/storage-sample-create-account#request-body).

That API does support the [optional parameter](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/storagerp/storageaccounts/create#request-body) `properties.allowBlobPublicAccess` so you should be able to add that directly in python as well.

Comment: Thanks for that ! but i've found this information already and couldn't implement it for existing storage account which is my primary request.

Comment: have you tried the update? https://github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-python/blob/master/sdk/storage/azure-mgmt-storage/tests/test_cli_mgmt_storage.py#L684

Comment: I tried and failed to implement it...nothing seems to work to change this property.